# Automatic lazy creation of automatic properties in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableArray*     myArray;
```

and I want to lazily create the array in the getter

```
- (NSMutableArray*)myArray
{
    if(_myArray == nil)
    {
        _myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
    }
    return _myArray;
}
```

but this breaks the automatic synthesis of the iVar (`_myArray), negating some of the benefits of automatic synthesis meaning you have to do things the old way.

This is a very common pattern and it would be nice to have automatic synthesis of a lazy-create version of the getter. I guess this would take an extension to the Objective-C language and compilers, for example with an additional property attribute like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly, lazycreate) NSMutableArray*     myArray;
```

Any class that implements a pre-defined class method (in a similar way to [object subscripting described here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)) such as `+ (ClassType*)defaultConstructor` could support the `lazycreate` property attribute and automatic synthesis could then synthesize the getter in my example like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)myArray
{
    if(_myArray == nil)
    {
        _myArray = [NSMutableArray defaultConstructor];
    }
    return _myArray;
}
```

Am I right that this would require a language extension, or is there a clever way to achieve it now?

Are there any problems or pitfalls with this idea and what are they?

How do I propose this idea into the Objective-C language?

Comment: It only breaks it if you use the readonly option. In the cases where you use that, is it really so hard to write, @synthesize myArray = _myArray;?

Comment: No, it's not hard. The primary benefit of synthesized code is that it is more reliable (less error-prone) than manually written code. Not having to type a line is a relatively minor benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new property attribute like `lazycreate` requires modifying the compiler.  You can ask Apple to add it by opening a new problem at http://bugreport.apple.com.  The product is “Developer Tools” and the classification is “Feature (New)”.

You could define a macro like this:

```
#define synthesizeLazy(Type, Property) \
    synthesize Property = _##Property; \
    - (Type *)property { \
        if (_##Property == nil) { _##Property = [[Type alloc] init]; } \
        return _##Property; \
    }
```

and then use it to synthesize your lazy properties like this:

```
@synthesizeLazy(NSMutableArray, myArray);
```

There's no good way to fake it with completely automatic synthesis.

Comment: That's a really good idea for how to do it now. Then the default constructor method could be added to supported classes in categories. Also, if considered as a language extension an alternate @synthesize might be more appropriate than a property attribute. I don't actually want to do this in my code - I'm just exploring how the language might be extended and improved even more than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the metaprogramming methods available on NSObject, such as `-implementationForMethod`. This allows you to provide an implementation of a missing method at runtime.

You can use this to provide a getter/setter dynamically for any declared properties.

You might then read from a dictionary of default values..

You could also try overriding `-valueForUndefinedKey:`

This might help: https://gist.github.com/2370784